# Graphql using redux state as well as Apollo

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

I have a server side rendered app and want data to be accessible on the first render. If a user navigates to the next page, I want to use the graphQL library Apollo to fetch the new content.

When a page is requested, the server sets the initialState key `curPage` with the data of the page that is requested. For example a user requests `http://example.com/about`. I get the page data for `/about` from my DB, set the initialState key `curPage` to that data from the DB.

So my initialState might look something like this:

```
{
  "curPage": {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "About",
    "slug": "about",
    "path": "/about",
    "template": "about",
    "published": "2017-07-10 02:02:30",
    "image": null,
    "seo": {
      "title": null,
      "description": null,
      "image": null,
      "fbAdmins": null,
      "gtm": null,
      "schema": ""
    },
    "sections": [
      {
        "type": "masthead",
        "mh_title": "",
        "video": false,
        "image": [

        ],
        "showCta": false,
        "cta": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "text_image",
        "alignment": "left",
        "text_image": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "title": "",
            "content": "",
            "call_to_action": false,
            "cta": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

So if that curPage data is available, I want to use that, otherwise I want to fetch from graphQL.

My page component currently only fetches from graphQL and doesn't check if the data is available in initialState.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { graphql, gql } from 'react-apollo';

import './about.css'

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className='about-container'>
        <h2>About Page</h2>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

const mapQueryToProps = ({data: { findResource }, ownProps}) =>
  ({ curPage: findResource ? findResource[0] : null })

const MY_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    findResource(filter: {resource: "pages", slug: "about"}) {
        id
        title
        slug
        path
        sections
    }
  }`

 export default graphql(MY_QUERY, { props: mapQueryToProps })(About)
```

Is there a way through Apollo graphQL that I can do something like react-redux's `connect()` does but if it isn't available then fetch from graphQL?

I'm guessing I need to use `connect()` but then in my `componentDidMount()` check if the data is set and if it's not retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the curData into the Apollo graphql format and use it to initialize the Apollo section of the store.

You can read about the specific here: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/server-side-rendering.html#store-rehydration

Note that Apollo actually supports server side rendering, so if you use Apollo Graphql on the server, it will actually generate the state that you need to send to the client to use to initialize the client-side Redux store

Comment: Cool, will take a look. Thanks